# Strange results in pivot query

Tags: sql, sqlfiddle

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9525/5 strange result in TO FIND OUT MORE ABOUT column row 2 "{ "2": "(null)" }"

Targeting both 2008 and 2012, shouldn't it just be null?

Is this schema/query correct?

Thanks,
P.

Comment: I think it is a bug in sqlfiddle, look it works fine in stackexchange data explorere, see a [demo here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/135213)

Comment: Nice, thanks Mahmoud.